# XAMPP server can't execute pages after activate eAccelerator (PHP Accelerator) in XAMPP under Linux

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, lampp, eaccelerator

Thanks for your time,

I am learning how to run and use Symfony 2 using this:
http://www.anilsagar.com/content/symfony2-tutorial-part-2-how-install-symfony2-linux-ubuntu-operating-system

You can see there Is nothing relevant or a problem. In fact, **I can even see the default config dashboard**. The problem is in the config screen because Symfony recommends to active *PHP Accelerator* and to disable *short_open_tag* flags. The *short_open_tag* can be disabled without noticeable problems but I cannot active *PHP Accelerator* using the XAMPP instructions from its faq:
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#mmcache

The faq says that uncommenting this in the php.ini file will enable PHP Accelerator:

```
;extension="eaccelerator.so"
;eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
;eaccelerator.cache_dir="/opt/lampp/tmp/eaccelerator"
;eaccelerator.enable="1"
;eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
;eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
;eaccelerator.debug="0"
;eaccelerator.filter=""
;eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
;eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
;eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
;eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
;eaccelerator.compress="1"
;eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

So I uncomment it:

```
; disabled in XAMPP 1.7.2 because incompatible with PHP 5.3.0
extension="eaccelerator.so"
eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
eaccelerator.cache_dir="/opt/lampp/tmp/eaccelerator"
eaccelerator.enable="1"
eaccelerator.optimizer="1"
eaccelerator.check_mtime="1"
eaccelerator.debug="0"
eaccelerator.filter=""
eaccelerator.shm_max="0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl="0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"
eaccelerator.shm_only="0"
eaccelerator.compress="1"
eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
```

But... it does not work. When I run any XAMPP page or symfony config page **it returns the PHP file** or something I do not understand!! (?).

You can see the text over the uncommented code in php.ini:

```
; disabled in XAMPP 1.7.2 because incompatible with PHP 5.3.0
```

But the version of XAMPP I am using use PHP +5.4

Thanks for your time.

PS: I am using Symfony 2, the latest version available right now 2.1.3 and XAMPP 1.8.1; All running under Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using eAccelerator, then you WILL have problems, probably with Doctrine. The reason is eAccelerator removes annotations from the code!!! As you may know, annotations play an essential role in Symfony2 and Doctrine. Either deactivate eAccelerator or install a different one. Take a look at: http://wildlyinaccurate.com/eaccelerator-and-doctrine-2

Comment: Wow. Even if eAccelerator is recommended by Symfony2. So you recommend me disable it despite of symfony2 "highly recommendation"? Well, haha, ok

Comment: Well, they recommend to use a bite code cache (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html) like APC, there are many (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators), but certainly eAccelerator is a poor choice for Symfony and any project depending on annotations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know it. I will try to install APC instead.